# How to RunComplie on updated template using same key in RazorEngine?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, razorengine

```
string template = "Hello @Model.Name, welcome to RazorEngine!";
var result = Engine.Razor.RunCompile(template, "templateKey", null, new { Name = "World" });
```

Now i update my existing template to as below. I get my template from database.

```
string template = "Hello @Model.Name, welcome to My World!";
```

Whenever i do that i get an error *The same key was already used for another template*.

What is the best way to fix this issue?

Comment: Every template should have it's own unique key,. Check if the template has already been used with `Engine.Razor.IsTemplateCached` and use `Run` instead of `RunCompile` if it's already there.

Comment: @DavidG It would be great if you can give me an example of this.

Comment: See this for context - https://stackoverflow.com/a/42120461/3333134

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The issue is that you are not using a template key that is unique to the template code you are passing in. `RazorEngine` caches the templates and compiles them so the next time round it's faster to run.

```
var helloTemplate = "Hello @Model.Name";

string result;
var model = new { Name = "World" };

//Has the template already been used? If so, Run without compilation is faster
if(Engine.Razor.IsTemplateCached("helloTemplate", null))
{
    result = Engine.Razor.Run("helloTemplate", null, model);
}
else
{
    result = Engine.Razor.RunCompile(helloTemplate, "helloTemplate", null, model);
}
```

Comment: even if i update the template. It's still use the cache template when i run it second time. I am using LINQPad 4 for testing this issue.

Comment: If you update the template, then you need a new key - that is a different template. There's no way to clear the cache in `RazorEngine` as they are compiled as assemblies and it's impossible to unload an assembly. you could get round this by using a new engine instance: `var engine = RazorEngineService.Create(); engine.RunCompile(...);` but that will not release the memory from the previous template.

Comment: That mean every time i update the template i need to create a new key and compile it again. There is no way i can delete the old template from cache.

Comment: That's what I said, yes. The only way to clear the cache is to restart the `AppDomain`.

Comment: I found this link https://github.com/Antaris/RazorEngine/blob/master/doc/TemplateManager.md . I update the code to use `MyTemplateManager()` and it's working fine. I am not sure if it's creating new key every time or using the same key and update new template. ```var config = new TemplateServiceConfiguration();
 config.Debug = true;
 config.TemplateManager = new MyTemplateManager(template); 
 
 Engine.Razor = RazorEngineService.Create(config);
 Engine.Razor.RunCompile(template, null, viewModel).Dump();```   I can update template using same key.

Comment: That's basically doing the same thing as I said above, the templates are still being put into a cache.